# Number of APP IDs created using an Apple individual developers account

Tags: iphone, app-id

How many APP IDs can be created using an Apple individual developers account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no limit to App IDs. But there is a limit of 100 device s you can register to test your applications.

Comment: is this same with enterprise account?

Answer (score 0):

Developer account restricted for devices count (100) not for applications. The small logic is you can create "N" number of application with a single  developer account.